# set data from codebehind for showing a chart in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I am trying to show a graph like one below image. I am able to populate it using dummy values in javascript, but unable to populate it using my real values either from code behind of java script.

Here is the javascript code the produces below shown graph with dummy data

```
 //chart with points
        if ($("#sincos").length) {
            var sin = [], cos = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < 64; i += 0.5) {
                sin.push([i, Math.sin(i) / i]);
                cos.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);
            }

            var plot = $.plot($("#sincos"),
                [
                    { data: sin, label: "Estimated Time"},
                    { data: cos, label: "Actual Time" }
                ], {
                    series: {
                        lines: { show: true  },
                        points: { show: true }
                    },
                    grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true, backgroundColor: { colors: ["#fff", "#eee"] } },
                    yaxis: { min: -1.2, max: 1.2 },
                    colors: ["#539F2E", "#3C67A5"]
                });}
```

[image: Here is the output of the above java script code]

**sin, cos arrays are being filled in a for loop above with dummy data.**

Now my real data that I want to plot is like this
Project ref # (string), estimated time(integer), actual time(integer).

I want to populate scheduled time vs actual time of the project's ref #.
Ref# will appear on x-axis while time should appear on y-axis.

I want to serialize this data from code behind and populate it in graph like its done in dummy data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You don't mention what you are using to create your charts.  The JS snippet above on its own is not enough.

Comment: I have picked up an open source javascript code library to plot the charts. The only problem is how should I give the input similar to the way I have done in the above sample. in above sample sin and cos arrays are being filled with dummy values. and they are being plotted. I want to have real  values in sin and cos arrays.